# How to append json data into a file?

Tags: json, node.js

```js
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
var data = require('./data.json');
var items = data.items;
data.items[items.length] = {
  msg: "A new message"
};



jsonfile.writeFile('./data.json', data, {
  spaces: 2
}, function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

```css
{
  "items": [ {
    "name": "Tom", "time": "7.4.2016 3:13PM", "msg": "message1"
  }
  ,
  {
    "name": "Tom", "time": "7.4.2016 3:13PM", "msg": "message2"
  }
  ,
  {
    "name": "Tom", "time": "7.4.2016 3:13PM", "msg": "message3"
  }
  ]
}
```

I need to maintain a json file whose data style looks like the code above using node.js. And I should continuously add objects into the "items" array. However, I have to load and save the whole bunch of data every time I want to add a new item, if I adopt the method in the code above.
So my question is:
Is there a method to manipulate the json file directly, with no trouble of loading and saving the whole data(just like dealing with a database system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself loading and saving a "whole bunch of data" and are looking for ways to append json, that's a sign you need a database.

There's the typical mongodb, etc... servers.  But if your needs are simple you can also look at simple embedded DBs like [NEDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb).  This (and other embedded dbs) are file based DBs and they've solved the problem for you.  No reason to be 'like a database system'.   Just use one :)

Another possibility if you have to stay with a files approach is to write individual files or if that's too many files, then you could write "pages" of items.  But the feasibility depends on your read patterns.

But once again, a db is probably more appropriate if you're in this state asking these questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really, not as long as the file looks like that (meaning you are applying styling to the output). You *might* be able to easily append if you instead just had one "entry" per line (this is what you should get when you don't have `spaces: 2`), then you could just:

```
fs.appendFile('./foo.json', JSON.stringify(obj) + '\n', callback);
```

to append without `JSON.parse()` and a subsequent `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: good idea! but using this method, i can only get the json file with separate objects, like this: {} \n {} \n {} \n, so can I iterate all the objects in this json file?

Comment: Sure, just read the file, taking note of each newline. For example, if you're looking for a specific index, just count the number of newlines until you reach the index you want, then start buffering data until you see the next newline. Then parse that buffered data.